# Spring Oauth2 - override TokenEndpoint allowed methods

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I need to allow users to get an OAuth token via grant_type=password and using GET and not POST. The default implementation for [TokenEndpoint](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/endpoint/TokenEndpoint.html) is as follows:

```
public class TokenEndpoint extends AbstractEndpoint {

private OAuth2RequestValidator oAuth2RequestValidator = new DefaultOAuth2RequestValidator();

private Set<HttpMethod> allowedRequestMethods = new HashSet<HttpMethod>(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.POST));

@RequestMapping(value = "/oauth/token", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> getAccessToken(Principal principal, @RequestParam
Map<String, String> parameters) throws HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException {
    if (!allowedRequestMethods.contains(HttpMethod.GET)) {
        throw new HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException("GET");
    }
    return postAccessToken(principal, parameters);
}
```

As you can see, the default allowed is only POST. I am using XML configuration (not annotations). How can I add to the Set the HttpMethod.GET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following config worked:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
protected static class AuthorizationServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
                .requestFactory(defaultOAuth2RequestFactory)
                .authenticationManager(myUserAuthenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(myTokenStore)
                .allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST);// to allow get for password grant
            ;

        }
@Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
            security
                .realm(REALM)
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients()// to let users do password grant with username/ password on get
                ;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

With just XML config it's not possible to configure the allowed token end point methods.

That leaves you with two options:

- move everything to Java config (as checklist's answer)
- create an extra configuration class that will run a `@PostConstruct` method after the XML has run, to finish the job.

Java config is probably what you should be using for a new app, but if you've got an older app that's using XML config, then something like this will work:

```
@Configuration
public class AllowedMethodConfig {
    @Autowired
    private TokenEndpoint tokenEndpoint;

    @PostConstruct
    public void reconfigure() {
        Set<HttpMethod> allowedMethods =
            new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST));
        tokenEndpoint.setAllowedRequestMethods(allowedMethods);
    }
}
```