# Spring OAuth2 authorization server allow GET method in introspect

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I been looking way to configure or customize the the `/oauth2/introspect` to `GET` method.

As per [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32109860/spring-oauth2-override-tokenendpoint-allowed-methods) this is deprecated and not working.

As a default `/oauth2/introspect` is `POST` but the requirement is allow `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

What you ask is impossible: an "OAuth2 authorization server" cannot accept `GET` requests on introspection endpoint. **As per [OAuth2 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7662#section-2.1), an introspection request must be a `POST` with parameters sent as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**. It also must be secured (accessible to authorized clients only).